# How does ENS pricing works

Tags: ether, gas-price, ens, decentralization, price

I am just looking for the prices for the ENS.
 Can anyone help me understand the economics of ENS domain, their price depends on the fluctuations of Ethereum and if we assume that it'll always go up then the very simple thing like domain registering would be impossible to purchase in ENS(Currently it is 348$ to register a domain).
How onboarding of new users which is really important for the adoption of any technology will become with this pricing?
How ethereum developers/team is thinking of tackling this problem?
Also, are there any solutions ongoing for the high gas issue too?
I am really intrigued by this whole decentralized technology that is why I am trying to learn as much as I can.
 Any literature directions to read are also welcome.

Comment: Registering a domain costs [$5 fee + gas](https://docs.ens.domains/permanent-registrar-faq#how-much-will-the-yearly-renewals-cost). It’s currently expensive because the gas price is very high at ~320 gwei; in calmer periods it can cost 10 times less.